# Unable to get var value inside function

Tags: wordpress, function, http-post-vars

I am trying to get `field_1` value into the input text and I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
function bbg_add_reg_field() {
  $field_1= $_POST["signup_username"];  
  echo '<input name="field_1" id="field_1" value="$field_1" type="text">';  
}
add_action( 'bp_before_registration_submit_buttons', 'bbg_add_reg_field' );
```

The echo value shown inside the input text is `$field_1`

The value should be a name, say for example `peter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can interpolate a string (add variables to a string with $var) only when it is a double quoted string.

From the PHP Documentation

```
// Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
```

Instead you could do this

```
echo '<input name="field_1" id="field_1" value="' . $field_1 . '" type="text">';
```

oh and don't forget htmlspecialchars

```
echo '<input name="field_1" id="field_1" value="' . htmlspecialchars($field_1) . '" type="text">';
```

You could also achieve the same using PHP Heredoc. Which goes like this

```
echo <<<EOF
<input name="field_1" id="field_1" value="$field_1" type="text">
EOF;
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? echo "<input name='field_1' id='field_1' value='$field_1' type='text'>";

Comment: You string concatenation like i showed. or use a double quoted string with double quotes escaped. Its your choice really. Concatenation would look cleaner IMO

Comment: thank you Ahmed, this code works. echo '<input name="field_1" id="field_1" value="' . $field_1 . '" type="text">';